# Get unix 'top' command output from expect script

Tags: unix, expect

All,
I want to execute a unix statement in expect script.The unix statement outputs  rsize value for a process.  I haven't programmed in expect before.
This is my code:

```
 #!/usr/bin/expect
 set some_host "some host"
 set Mycmd "top -l 1 -stats pid,rsize,command | grep Process_Name| awk '{print \$2};'"
 spawn telnet localhost $some_host
 expect "login:"
 send "myDevice\r"
 expect "Password:"
 send "$password\r"
 expect "\$"
 send "$Mycmd\r"
```

When I execute this, I don't get any output. What's the correct syntax to execute the unix statement? How do I get this to work so that I get the correct rsize value as the output?

Comment: What version of Unix? Login and type 'man top' and look at the command. Also, try this on serverfault.com

Comment: Then your top command is fine (at least on my OS X) - try removing the  \ on the $2

Comment: If I remove the \ I get an error:                                  can't read "2": no such variable
    while executing
"set Mycmd "top -l 1 -stats pid,rsize,command | grep Process_Name| awk '{print $2};'""                                                  FYI: top command works fine on my Mac OSX. I don't get an output when i execute the expect script

Comment: What output do you get otherwise?

Comment: @Ed : I'm getting an output now. I  modified the expect script and added "interact" to the end of the script. That executed the unix statement and I got an output( btw, rsize is the resident memory size of a process and the output is like 70M+,70M,70M-) . Is it possible to get the output without having to add the "interact" statement

Comment: Probably not... interact opens the stdout/stdin to the user. Without that you probably just were not seeing the output b/c it was not directed to your pty.

Answer (score 0):

Always a good idea to try to escape with ascii, try \0442 for \$2 or try something like \\$2
.Also you can debug the script to find why you have no output if you insert 'exp_internal 1' without quotes at the second line.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to get the output without having to add the "interact" statement

Yes, it is. Other statements which wait for the output will also do; you could add e. g.

```
expect -re "\n\[0-9]+"
```

to the end of your script.